# PTC integrity checking in unchanged files

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

while testing the performance of PTC integrity via script using CLI calls, we do the following.
We are trying to create different versions of the project and gather the time taken to do so. For this the different versions of the project (contents) is available in seperate folders.
The script does the following 
- Does a lock of the project

> si lock --yes --recurse --cpid=:bypass

- delete the contents of the sandbox, except the .pj file
- copy the next version contents from the corresponding local copy to the sandbox. This simulates changes made to some artifacts in the sandbox.
- Find Missing files , collect it in an array

> si viewsandbox --batch --yes --recurse --sandbox= path\project.pj --filter=changed:missing --fields=name

- Loop through the array above and drop each member

> si  drop --cpid=:bypass --yes --batch --sandbox=path\project.pj each_member

- Check in all "changed" members/files

> "si ci --recurse --nocheckinUnchanged --filter=changed:working  ––nounexpand  --cpid=:bypass --sandbox=path\project.pj --description="test"

- Find non-members, collect it in arrat

> si viewnonmembers --batch --yes --recurse --fields=absolutepath --sandbox= path\project.pj --cwd=path

- Loop through the array and add each non-member

> si add --createSubprojects  --nounexpand --batch --cpid=:bypass --sandbox=path\project.pj each_non-member

- unlock

> si unlock --action=remove --yes --recurse

- Create Check point.

> si checkpoint --yes --sandbox=\project.pj --label=LabelName --description="test"

Above Steps are done for the number of such project versions that i need to create.

In the project policies, "Store text by Reference=true" is set.
Integrity version is 10.

Now my problem. : For each version of the project i am creating by the above steps, it is creating a new version for all files, irrespective it is changed or not. When member history is viewed for such files, it does not show any difference between 2 versions created. Have you faced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

this is 'cause you delete all your files in the sandbox. The new files have a different time stamp and therefore PTC regards them as new. There is no real DIFF made by PTC, afaik it checks only the timestamp(last change).

All i can think of is, only delete files that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your sandbox to check diff by checksum.[image]

This can/shall be set by default for all Sandboxes by your Admin.